# django is it faster to go to settings or database

Tags: django, django-models, django-settings

I am using the sites framework in django.  I have a context processor that gives me access to the sites framework which is stored as a model in the database.  I could also store the same values in settings.

Is it more efficient to store and retrieve info like site name from the model or from a property in settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to the sites framework, the sites are cached by default and as fast as your settings.

It would be a good idea to keep your settings module for just settings, not as some sort of ad hoc caching mechanism or a replacement for the sites framework.

Answer (score 1):

The settings are cached by default, the database is not. So the settings are definitely faster.

Both are cacheable however so in the end it doesn't matter too much depending on how you use it. Also, it will probably have a negligible amount of influence.